Is there a List with indexing possibilities?
I currently have the following kind of code:
List<Product> products = Db.GetAllProducts(database);

foreach (var part in ListOfParts)
{
    if (part.ProductId != null)
    {
        if (products.Where(o => o.Id == part.ProductId).FirstOrDefault() == null)
        { ...}

You can see that I'm doing quite a lot of produces.Where(o => o.Id == ...).FirstOrDefault().
While working with a table (general database technology), it's possible to add an index in order to speed up searching.
Does such a thing also exist for System.Generic.Collections.List class, or for another class in the System.Generic.Collections namespace?

a list is not keyed; a dictionary is keyed - are you after a dictionary? maybe var products = Db.GetAllProducts(database).ToDictionary(x => x.Id); ?

that said: it would be better to limit the DB fetch to just the products that you know you need - the ListOfParts.Select(x => x.ProductId).Distinct().ToList()

You're thinking about this the wrong way.
As you said, in a database this index will (typically) already exist, and this looks like Entity Framework... which will let you structure the code to take advantage of the index such that only the matching records are ever returned to your app at all.
This greatly reduces memory use in both your app and on the database server, and greatly reduces time waiting for the data transfer over the wire.
That is, loading the whole table to a list is pretty much always a mistake in the first place.
It's also typically better to prefer using an IQueryable<T> or IEnumerable<T> in your app code over a list for as long as possible. This includes when defining things like method arguments and return types.
But I think I get what you're trying to do: this is a bunch of separate queries to the table in a tight loop. It seems like it should be better to cache the data locally once for this process.
That idea is still mistaken.
I do understand this specific code might be a little trickier, but it is still possible to send the whole set of parts up to the database as a table-value parameter you can use in a JOIN, to get this down to ONE ROUND TRIP to and from the database, where only the matching records are ever transferred or held in memory.
I'm personally more of a bare-SQL guy, so I won't attempt here to show what that will look like as EF code. In fact, this is a good demonstration for why I don't really love ORMs: when it comes down to it, you still have know about the SQL you need to create, and now you also need to know what to do to get your ORM to generate your desired SQL. This means an ORM ultimately tends to increase cognitive load on the developer, since now you have to know about both. ORMs are only really useful for the simplest of queries, and those were easy to build the SQL for anyway.
I'll finish by saying it's likely the ListOfParts set is also based on criteria from the database in the first place. It could be based on user selections, but database criteria is just as likely, in which case this should be structured more as a normal JOIN from the beginning, at the point when the parts list is first loaded.

So you want to find and process all parts which have a non existing product? Let the database find them, so don't use a loop so early and ask for each part the Database. Do you have already loaded that local list of parts into memory or do you get them from the DB, then you could optimize the query further. If the former you could use this approach:
var partsWithProductId = ListOfParts.Where(p => p.ProductId != null);
IQueryable<Part> partsWithNonExistingProduct = db.Parts
    .Where(p => partsWithProductId.Contains(p.Id) 
            && !db.Products.Any(p => p.Id == part.ProductId)); 

Now you can use a foreach loop to process the parts and  you need only one request to the DB.
